# How to redirect users based on customer/admin role on asp.net using logins from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, boolean

I am trying to redirect users to either an admin homepage or a customer homepage based on their roles.

Using SQL, users must login with their email and password, and then I have set the Admin column to Bit so they are either Admin true or false.

This is my code, I am not sure what I am missing/ doing wrong as the user is being redirected to the "AdminDefault" page no matter their role.

**P.S I am a newbie still learning.**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Shotz.Pages
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool isLoggedIn = false;
            string email = string.Empty;
            string password = string.Empty;

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                email = txtEmail.Text;
                password = txtPassword.Text;

                isLoggedIn = IsValidLoginCredentials(email, password);

                if (isLoggedIn)
                {
                    //if the user name is valid add the username to the session and redirect the user to the admin home page
                    Session.Add("email", email);
                    Boolean checkUserType = checkUser();

                    if (checkUserType)
                        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/AdminDefault.aspx");
                    else
                        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Default.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    //if the login is invald tell the user
                    lblLoginDetails.Text = "Invalid Login Details - please try again!";
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsValidLoginCredentials(string email, string password)
        {
            int rowCount = 0;

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Users] WHERE [Email] = @email AND [Password] = @password";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

            connection.Open();

            rowCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

            connection.Close();

            return (rowCount == 1);
        }

        protected Boolean checkUser()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            //define sql query
            connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT Admin FROM Users WHERE [Admin] = 'True'";

           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            String Admin = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            if (Admin == "True")
            {
                return true;
            }

            connection.Close();

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on `checkUser` function you need to verification this login user is or isn't *Admin*,otherwise the users will be *Admin* when there is any *Admin* exist on the `[Users]` table.

So adding two parameter on `checkUser(string email, string password)` email and passwrod be the parameter

The code would be like this.

```
protected Boolean checkUser(string email, string password)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    //define sql query
    connection.Open();
    string query = "SELECT Admin FROM Users WHERE [Admin] = 'True' and [Email] = @email AND [Password] = @password";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

    String Admin = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    if (Admin == "True")
    {
        return true;
    }
    connection.Close();

    return false;
}
```

When you use you would be like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isLoggedIn = false;
    string email = string.Empty;
    string password = string.Empty;
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        email = txtEmail.Text;
        password = txtPassword.Text;

        isLoggedIn = IsValidLoginCredentials(email, password);

        if (isLoggedIn)
        {
            Session.Add("email", email);
            Boolean checkUserType = checkUser(email, password);

            if (checkUserType)
                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/AdminDefault.aspx");

            else
                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblLoginDetails.Text = "Invalid Login Details - please try again!";
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can try to use `DataTable`

```
protected Boolean checkUser(string email, string password)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    //define sql query
    connection.Open();
    string query = "SELECT Admin FROM Users WHERE [Admin] = 1 and [Email] = @email AND [Password] = @password";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    } 


    connection.Close();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried updating the checkUser fucntion to the above and now I am getting the error "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'email' " in the above IF statment on "Boolean checkUserType = checkUser();" ?

Comment: You need to pass your parameter when you call the method ..`Boolean checkUserType = checkUser(email, password);`

Comment: I updated using your advice and was getting the error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteScalar(...) returns null." so I changed "String Admin = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();" to "String Admin = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;". But now both of the users are being directed to the "default" page instead one the admin to the "admindefault" . Should I use something else instead of "String Admin = command.ExecuteScalar() as string" ?

Comment: The error is you can't find any user by username and email,I edit my answer you could try it out :)

Comment: Where "if (result != null && "true" == Admin.ToString().ToLower())" , it says "the name 'Admin' does not exist in the current context"    :(

Comment: Oops I wrote the wrong name `result` instead of `Admin` @N.L

Comment: It is still directing all users to "default" page, could this be a problem with sql data?     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Admin]    BIT            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);

Comment: That `[Admin]` column type is `BIT` so I think you need to check exist by `[Admin] = 1`,I edit my answer
Could you provide some data from your `Users`  table?

Comment: Sure the data I am testing with is   Insert into Users values 
('admin@shotz.ie', 'admin', '1'),
('john@shotz.ie', 'hello123', '0');

Comment: They are both still directing to "default"

Comment: weird,It is work to me. or you can try another way use `DataTable`,you can follow my edit answer